# Why getting error "Not a valid URL" when trying to add webCal to Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar, webcal

I am getting "Not a Valid URL" when trying to add a webCal to Google Calendar. The URL is given below

```
webcal://brearley.myschoolapp.com/podium/feed/iCal.aspx?z=1gyQEon7fPm2b9em9JTthTLAhu4i5rQ0HvxYZYPf7NXtLERe3aOxlIqu53HLmjTK9pcMRCrf9%2fwEJFqvJzBccw%3d%3d
```

I am new to WebCal and Google Calendar. I need to know where I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sort it out myself. I just replaced the webcal with http and it worked.

```
http://brearley.myschoolapp.com/podium/feed/iCal.aspx?z=1gyQEon7fPm2b9em9JTthTLAhu4i5rQ0HvxYZYPf7NXtLERe3aOxlIqu53HLmjTK9pcMRCrf9%2fwEJFqvJzBccw%3d%3d
```

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally unsubscribed a calendar. I found the url in the Google calendar API list, but kept getting "invalid url" when trying to add a calendar "from url". I went to "subscribe to calendar" instead, pasted in the url and it worked.